# Coriander substitute?

Tags: substitutions, spices

I have a recipe where one of spices I need to use is coriander. What other spice can I use to substitute coriander and don't change taste very much?

In the recipe coriander is used to season meat before cooking.

Comment: 'Coriander' can refer to the seed (US) or to the leaves (UK) ... as you said 'spices', I assume it's the seed, but there might be translation assues, and you might be doing a chimichurri-like marinade, where you'd be using the leaf.  Could you clarify which one the recipe calls for?  (or even give the recipe ... it might help people to recommend a substitution)

Comment: I meant seeds. In the recipe it was used to rub the meat before cooking along with the cumin, garlic and all spice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The coriander seed has a fresh lemony flavor. I really dig it. It isn't very similar to the coriander herb, cilantro, but it has a similar freshness.

The problem is how you are cooking the meat. Coriander is dry and can be toasted; other substitutions such as herbs might burn.

These suggestion won't taste just like coriander but they are filed in similar categories in my mind. They would create the same mood.

If you need dry or toasted spice- such as for a rub you might try lemon-pepper or a little toasted fennel for the sweet freshness.

If this is a marinade and you aren't worried about burning the spices you could try lemon zest with a little cilantro.

Answer (score 4):

Sobachatina offers very good advice. I would add dry roasted, ground caraway seeds combined with cumin and some lemon zest. Your recipe already calls for cumin.